# Derivation for the second order expansion in the paper "Additive Logistic Regression: A Statistical View of Boosting"

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, generalized-additive-model, ensemble-learning, mathematical-statistics

I need help with a derivation. In the paper "Additive Logistic Regression: A Statistical View of Boosting". The authors make a second order approximation about $f(x)=0$ to the following function

$J(F(x)+cf(x)) = E[e^{-yF(x)-cf(x)}]$

(Note: $c$ and $x$ are both fixed)

(see Result 1 on page 346: 
[Additive Logistic Regression: A Statistical View of Boosting](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/AdditiveLogisticRegression/alr.pdf)).

My derivation is close to their result, but I cannot figure out where the "$f(x)$" and "$f(x)^{2}$" comes from. Here is my second order approximation:

$J(F(x)+cf(x))=E[e^{-yF(x)-ycf(x)}] \approx$

$= E[e^{-yF(x)-yc(0)} + e^{-yF(x)-ycf(x)}yc(1))*(F(x) + cf(x) -0) + \frac{e^{-yF(x)-ycf(x)}yc(yc)*(F(x) + cf(x) -0)^{2}}{2!}] $

Setting the $f(x)$ terms in the derivative expressions only yields the following:

$= E[e^{-yF(x)} + e^{-yF(x)-yc0}yc(1))*(F(x) + cf(x) -0)$

$ + \frac{e^{-yF(x)-yc0}yc(yc)*(F(x) + cf(x) -0)^{2}}{2!}] $

$= E[e^{-yF(x)} (1 + yc(F(x)+cf(x)) + \frac{y^{2}c^{2}(F(x)+cf(x))^{2})}{2!}]$

The result in the paper is the following (second line of their proof):

$= E[e^{-yF(x)} (1 + ycf(x) + y^{2}c^{2}f(x)^{2})]$

Are the authors just ignoring the $F(x)$ since they are only expanding about $f(x)=0$ as oppposed to expanding about $F(x) + cf(x) = 0$?